# How to fix the error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, relative-import

I've: `db = SQLAlchemy()` inside  **init**.py and I want to import db to models.py

When I try to do: `from . import db` I get the Error:  ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I've tried several things like:

```
import db

from .. import db
 
from website import db
```

When I run `from __init__ import db` it shows no error until I run main.py, then it shows the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**init**'

My program is structured like this:

```
> Web app 
    > main.py
    >website
       >__init__.py
       >auth.py
       >models.py
       >views.py
       >templates
           >base.html
           >login.html
           >home.html
           >sign-up.html
```

**Please help!**

Comment: In general you shouldn't define things in \_\_init__.py that you want things in the same package to access. Move the definition into a separate file and then import it into \_\_init__.py if you need other things outside the package to access it that way.

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: I´m sorry this is my first program. What do you mean with how am i running the code? Do you want me to show you the complete code?